# iOS how to get CPU architecture given NXGetLocalArchInfo has been deprecated?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a "device info" app and it shows the CPU architecture. I have been using this code which works fine.

```
  func getArchitecture() -> String? {
    guard
      let info = NXGetLocalArchInfo(),
      let string = info.pointee.description
    else { return nil }
    return String(utf8String: string)
  }
```

The `NXGetLocalArchInfo` function has been deprecated in iOS 16, and I don't know what to use instead.

Edit: After some research, it looks like the new API should be `macho_arch_name_for_mach_header`: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/commit/19c1b15f7c012b0633eb74fd2effd961c88d28a3

However, I don't know how to write it in Swift. Please help.

Comment: `macho_arch_name_for_mach_header` in Objective-C is found in `<mach-o/utils.h>` but in Swift there doesn't seem to be a `MachO.utils`.

Comment: yeah, importing MachO alone doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Objective-C header file `<mach-o/arch.h>` shows that `NXGetLocalArchInfo` is deprecated and you should use `macho_arch_name_for_mach_header()`. `macho_arch_name_for_mach_header()` can be found in `<macho-o.utils.h>`.

Unfortunately, the `MachO` module (in both Objective-C and Swift) does not include the `utils` submodule.

One solution would be to write a simple Objective-C class that can import `<macho-o.utils.h>` and call `macho_arch_name_for_mach_header()`. Then this helper class can be called from Swift.

Here's an example implementation.

Start by adding a Cocoa Touch Class to your project. On the options screen for the new file, choose Objective-C as the language. Enter a name such as `ArchInfo` for the class and have it subclass `NSObject`.

If this is the first Objective-C code you've added to the Swift project, you will be prompted about adding a bridging header file. Choose the option to have this added. A file named something like `Project-Bridging-Header.h` will be added to the project.

Add the following line to the new (or your existing) bridging header file:

```objc
#import "ArchInfo.h" // Or whatever name you gave the new class
```

Update the contents of ArchInfo.h as follows:

```objc
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ArchInfo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, nullable, readonly, class) NSString *archName;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Update ArchInfo.m as follows:

```objc
#import "ArchInfo.h"
#import <mach-o/utils.h>

@implementation ArchInfo

+ (NSString *)archName {
    const char* name = macho_arch_name_for_mach_header(NULL);

    return name ? [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] : nil;
}

@end
```

Then in some Swift file you can do:

```swift
print("Arch name: \(ArchInfo.archName ?? "Unknown")")
```

When run on in an iOS simulator on my Intel Mac, the output is:

> Arch name: x86_64

Comment: is it doable using c code? so that i don't have to go through these trouble of bridge header etc. Iirc swift supports c inter-op

Comment: I've never tried to use straight C with Swift. There's certainly no reason that a C file can't include the needed header file and call `macho_arch_name_for_mach_header()`.

Comment: is there other ways of importing that util? can i import it in objc and re-exported to swift?

Comment: What I show in my answer is the only way I know how to make it work.